# how to extrude an edge that stays connected with the face?

Tags: modeling, objects, snapping, extrude

I'm trying to extrude the face to create another wall. It works out well but the vertex and edge are not connected to the floor even though it's level. Anyone know how to extrude so it stays connected with the face? If it's even possible.

Thx

Screenshots:
[image: Wall extruded]

[image: Lifted vertex that is not joined with the face]

Comment: Read about vertex snapping. This is but one link. https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your wall is orthogonal to the x-y-plane. Then there are several options to extrude the floor without loosing "connection" e.g. lifting your wall up.

If your plane is level you can easily lock the extrude to a plane by Extruding and then (while the extrude is active) press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> this will lock the movement to the x-y-plane. In case you want the extrude to be rectangular you can press <kbd>y</kbd> during the extrude to lock it to the Y-Axis. (This can be a powerful technique if you are comfortable with the different coordinate system orientations in blender) [Blender_Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/axis_locking.html?highlight=axis)

The other method is, as pointed out in the comment, using vertex snapping with the target being a plane. https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html%3E

Comment: That's the technique I use but it still won't stay connected. Same for duplication, I duplicate along X axis to place it further away from the 1st selection and it stays separate. 

Even tried separating from the object and connecting it back on and the vertexes still were loose from the plane. So for example; to make another pillar I have to use the knife tool which is not as accurate as duplicating(Would take long to get exact same size at least) 

Knife tool works well, but when I try to extrude/duplicate it just doesn't stay connected to the actual object.

Comment: Could you upload your blendfile?